# slideDown & slideUp issue

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have the following responsive site and i'm having an issue with the mobile nav menu:

http://www.endeavor.cl/

When you resize the window or load it in a mobile device, you have a menu with sub-menu items with a slide-down effect that show you the sub-menu items everytime you click on them and, if you click them again or click somewhere else, the sub-menu item will hide itself with a slide-up effect. The problem is when you resize the window again and click again the sub-menu items, they will now show and inmediately hide, like they execute the 2 steps without waiting for a second clicking.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function () {   
    if ($(window).width() >= 1000){ 
      $("#menu-top").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top").addClass("desktop");
    }else{
      $("#menu-top").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top").addClass("touch");
      $("#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children a").addClass("primer-boton").css('cursor','pointer');
      $("#menu-top.touch .sub-menu a").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top.touch .primer-boton").removeAttr("href");
      $('#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
        var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
        if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
        $(submenu).slideDown(200);
        } else {
        $(submenu).slideUp(900);
        }
      });
      
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because everytime window resize your code attach event listener again.
So it fires twice after resize. Firstly showing menu and then hiding it.

Do you really need that `resize` in `on` event? Maybe just `load` will meet your expectations

Comment: If i take out the resize event, the mobile version of the menu will not be displayed.

Comment: No! you're right! i don't really need the resize event, because when in a phone, the mobile version is already loaded, so i don't need the resize event at all.

Solved.